# Global PostProcess in UnrealEngine 4.10.2

Tags: unreal-4, post-processing

I am new to UnrealEngine and following few tutorials to get started with.

I am trying to find "Global PostProcess" (in World Outliner) in UnrealEngine 4.10, but I am not able to find it. Has it been changed compared to previous version of UnrealEngine? If so whats the alternative of it?

Thanks.

**Update**

This is what I have:

[image]

And it doesn't look anything like whats there in this link (see Assigning to a Post Process Volume)

https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Engine/Rendering/PostProcessEffects/PostProcessMaterials/PostProcessDemoMaterialOverview/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that what you need, it's to add a Post Process Volume to your map and set it up to Unbound. This will make your PPVolume "global", affecting everthing boundless.

[image]

[image]

Comment: But it doesn't look anything like what I have. Please look at my updated question

Comment: What you have in that outliner is just a post process volume like the one I posted, but put into the scene.